# How to get immediate child of <ul> using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, cheerio

I have html file html content like this :

```
<ul>
    <li class="class_1">111</li>
    <li class="class_2">
        <ul>
            <li class="class_3">222</li>
            <li class="class_4">333</li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li class="class_5">444</li>
</ul>
```

After Loading html content in cheerio module and while searching for immediate ***li*** childs it's getting all items from child ***ul*** as well like this :

```
this._$$=cheerio.load(<htmlContent>, {xmlMode : true});
const liElements = this._$$(`ul > *`);
```

When i print liElements in after converting to html content i am getting output like this :

```
<li class="class_1">111</li>
<li class="class_2">
     <ol>
         <li class="class_3">222</li>
         <li class="class_4">333</li>
     </ol>    
</li>
<li class="class_5">444</li>
<li class="class_3">222</li>
<li class="class_4">333</li>
```

You can see content from child ***ul*** is repeating here. I tried a lots of options from cheerio documentation but no luck. Can any help me to get immediate ***li*** child of ***ul***.

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: _"it's getting all items from child ul as well"_ - of course it does, because those LI are children of _a_ UL as well, so the selector `ul > *` matches. If you walked into a room and said, "all sons of parents, please move into that corner" - then not only your brother would have to move into that corner, but your father as well - because your father is himself also a son of parents. So if you want to limit this to a specific "generation", then you need to amend your selector with _something_ that selects only the top-level UL to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that `ul > *`is too generic and it will return all the ul child even ones inside ul under li tag

maybe you have two solutions to fix this situation

**1) put a class name on top ul**

```
<ul class="main-ul">
    <li class="class_1">111</li>
    <li class="class_2">
        <ul>
            <li class="class_3">222</li>
            <li class="class_4">333</li>
        </ul>    
    </li>
    <li class="class_5">444</li>
</ul>
```

selector became const liElements = this._$$(`.main-ul > li`);

**2) get child of ul inside li tag and remove them from list of all child**

```
const liWithLiParent= this._$$(`li > ul > *`);
const liElements = this._$$(`ul > *`).filter(li => !liWithLiParent.some(liWithParent => liWithParent === li));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is just to remove the child ul's

```
$('ul ul').remove()
```